# Is it possible to embed some value onto another string in Go?

Tags: string, go

Is it possible to embed some value inside a string? or copy some part of a string onto another in Go?
something like this:

Given these:

```
user_id := "100"
given_id := "12"
ip_address := "192.168.1.1"
```

i put inside     `string1 := "32characterstringgives128bitlong"`

and get something like this:

```
newString := "100harac12rstrin192.168.1.1tlong"
```

I want to clarify, I don't want to check or see if the string is contained in the other string. I want to insert some values or string into a specific part of another string.

So far i tried `copy()`and dividing into `[]byte` array to change the individual characters

```
pad1 := fmt.Sprintf("%-8", user_id)
pad2 := fmt.Sprintf("%-8", given_id)
pad3 := fmt.Sprintf("%-16", ip_address)

padded := string(pad1 + pad2 + pad3)
```

to get:`"1       1       192.168.1.1     "` 
which is 32 byte long and i would then add in the corresponding string value in the spaces like so:

```
for i := range string1 {
    if padded[i] == 32 {
        padded[i] = byte(string1[i]) //insert into padded's empty spaces
    }
}
```

the IDs and IP addresses could be longer or shorter than my example. so IDs could be like
id#1 = 1 and id#50 = 1001 and ip addresses could be like 
192.168.1.1 or 192.168.100.110 so i cant just append them together. That is why wanted to know if there was a way to change out specific parts of a string with other stuff

Comment: Strings in Go are *immutable* by design, you can't modify the contents of a string. You can, however, create a new string from other strings.

Comment: Are you trying to do some sort of steganography? What do you actually want to achieve? I am asking since I smell a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) here. Oh, and welcome to SO!

Comment: i wanted to generate specific tokens for each users connecting to my web. and it doesn't really have to be a string it can be a []byte don't really matter, i just want to get a result which i can use to hash

Comment: Slices in Go, byte or not, are mutable. You can modify the contents of a slice using index expression with assignment. Can you show what you've tried to modify a slice and include the errors you've got back, if any?

Comment: Also take a look at https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#insert, maybe it has something close to what you're looking for.

Comment: i did "padded[i] = byte(string1[i])" in the //insert into padded's empty spaces  
part and got  "cannot assign to padded[i]" error on the console

Comment: To overwrite parts or all of a slice use [copy](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy).

Comment: @EnkhboldMunkhbold as already mentioned *strings are immutable*, that means you simply cannot do `padded[i] = ...` if padded is of type `string`. Change `padded`'s type to `[]byte`, then you can do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @EnkhboldMunkhbold https://play.golang.com/p/iawP2LYj9I-

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    //declarations
    user_id := "1"
    given_id := "1"
    ip_address := "192.168.1.1"

    pad1 := fmt.Sprintf("%-8s", user_id)
    pad2 := fmt.Sprintf("%-8s", given_id)
    pad3 := fmt.Sprintf("%-16s", ip_address)

    mak := string(pad1 + pad2 + pad3)
    bytemak := []byte(mak)

    token := []byte("32characterstringgives128bitlong")

    for i := range token {
        if mak[i] == 32 {
            bytemak[i] = byte(token[i])
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(string(bytemak))
}
```

result:
`12charac1erstrin192.168.1.1tlong`